# Debian doesn't detect disks from Live CD

Tags: debian, live-usb, livecd

I've loaded from the USB stick with Debian Live CD on it to fix the MBR after a Windows installation.

Suddenly I've found that `fdisk -l` shows nothing but the live USB itself. What would it mean?

I've used this image: http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/i386/iso-hybrid/debian-live-6.0.5-i386-xfce-desktop.iso

Comment: Are you running `fdisk -l` as root? If so, are there any strange messages in `dmesg`?

Answer (score 2):

Chris Down was [right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55338/debian-doesnt-detect-disks-from-live-cd#comment76018_55338); I wasn't running with root permissions